# Why do I get an "Error converting value" exception when parsing with Json.Net

Tags: c#, json, file, class, parsing

I'm trying to parse data from a .json file, and put them in a list of a class called "Track"

The class looks like this:

```
public class Track
{
        public string Artist { get; set; }
        public string Album { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int TrackNumber { get; set; }
        public string Filepath { get; set; }
        public int SongLength { get; set; }
        public Color RGB { get; set; }
}
```

And my code looks like this:

```
private void Load()
    {
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("C:\Users\Swagger\Desktop\Test\MusicCacheP.json"))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            List<Track> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Track>>(json);
            MSG(items.Count.ToString());
            //MSG is just a function which gives me a messagebox. I'm too lazy to write the full messagebox.show.. ;)
        }

    }
```

And I don't know if this matters but here's some of the json code:

```
{"Artist":"Dirty South","Album":"Until the End","Title":"Until the End (Michael Brun Mix) [feat. Joe Gil]","TrackNumber":0,"Filepath":"\\\\DAVIDIOSO\\Users\\hasht_000\\Music\\Dirty South - Until the End (Michael Brun Mix) [feat. Joe Gil].mp3","SongLength":21,"RGB":""}
```

I haven't really used Json that much to know fully how it works. I'm the kind of person who likes to learn by doing. But if you have some good pages to read about json in C#, I'd be glad to read it :)

EDIT:

I'm going crazy! I can't figure out why I'm getting this exception..

I'm only getting exceptions for the file paths.

And the crazy thing is that I have another file with all the filepaths inside of it, which I also read with json. And that's working out great.

A "ghetto" solution would be to read that file which only contains filepaths and use that to fill my list of Track? But it would be nice to get this sorted out.. 
Any help is really appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2):

You have defined `RGB` as `Color` in your class and what you have in your `json` points to a string type. You can modify your class to have a string type `RGB` and later convert that string value to `Color`.

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public string Album { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int TrackNumber { get; set; }
    public string Filepath { get; set; }
    public int SongLength { get; set; }
    public string RGB { get; set; } //here
}
```

*To automatically create a class template from json use http://json2csharp.com/*

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem :( I'm still getting the same exception. "Error converting value "\\DAVIDIOSO\Users\hasht_000\Music\Dirty South - Until the End (Michael Brun Mix) [feat. Joe Gil].mp3" to type 'MediaplayerV2WPF.Track'. Path '[0]', line 1, position 109."

Comment: Doesn't 'MediaplayerV2WPF.Track' being in the error make it appear that it has nothing to do with the JSON deserialize but the actual value stored in 'Filepath'? I am probably off the mark here, but it appears that your JSON is deserializing just fine, the problem lays with you trying to load the track in Media Player with the file path provided by the JSON. Some escape sequences maybe?

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. But how would I get the json information into the class then? Isn't the way I did the "textbook" way?

Answer (score 2):

So, I feel quite embarrassed to have to answer this myself.

What I forgot to do, was to remove a letter "p" from the filereader. So it got the file with only filepaths for the music instead of artists, track names, album names etc etc...

I can't believe I didn't see it until now!

It's been like 2-3 days since I first got this problem and it was SUCH an easy fix..

Comment: Is this a working answer to your question?

Comment: For anyone in the reviews, this _is_ an answer to the question. The OP found that a typo was the cause of the problem, and he/she is explaining why. This information should not be in the question post.